# AWS Rekognition Detect Labels Error in android studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-rekognition

Following error message is shown when I implement these codes...

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext.getApplicationContext(),
            "us-west-2:...",// Identity Pool ID
            Regions.US_WEST_2 // Region
    );

    AmazonRekognitionClient rekognitionClient = new AmazonRekognitionClient(credentialsProvider); <--Error Here

DetectLabelsRequest request = new DetectLabelsRequest()
            .withImage(new Image()
                    .withBytes(imageBytes))
            .withMaxLabels(10)
            .withMinConfidence(77F);
```

Console Messsage: AmazonWebServiceClient: {cognito-identity, us-west-2} was not found in region metadata, trying to construct an endpoint using the standard pattern for this region: 'cognito-identity.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'.
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Loading credentials from SharedPreferences
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: No valid credentials found in SharedPreferences

Error Message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isInRegionOptimizedModeEnabled()Z in class Lcom/amazonaws/SDKGlobalConfiguration; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.amazonaws.SDKGlobalConfiguration' appears in /data/app/com.example.name.app-1/base.apk:classes11.dex)
                                                                              at com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory.getConfig(ClientConfigurationFactory.java:35)
                                                                              at com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognitionClient.<init>(AmazonRekognitionClient.java:210)
                                                                              at com.example.name.app.DetectLabelsExampleImageBytes.main(DetectLabelsExampleImageBytes.java:67)
                                                                              at com.example.name.app.PhotoActivity.detectHash(PhotoActivity.java:186)
                                                                              at com.example.name.app.PhotoActivity.onActivityResult(PhotoActivity.java:158)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6470)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3716)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3763)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1403)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Raf Thanks for a reply and I am a newbie here. I edited the question and I hope it may help you to figure out.